# Big Freeze or Heat Death?

Tags: cosmology, universe, space-expansion

I can't seem to find this on the Internet.... Which is most likely to occur to "end" the universe, the big freeze scenario? Or the heat death scenario?

P.s. When, if it does at all, will the universe reach absolute zero?

Comment: It won't reach absolute zero, so sayeth the almighty third law of thermodynamics

Comment: Thank you... That's one question down... Would you perhaps know the lowest temperature it could get?

Comment: It *could* asymptotically approach absolute zero in a heat death scenario. However, there isn't consensus on if it will suffer a heat death. Many believe that the inclusion of gravity into the prediction makes a heat death ending unjustified. The Big freeze scenario isn't different from the heat death, it is simply the case where the universe keeps expanding forever. It *could* also lead to heat death or it might not.

Comment: It's not obvious to me what the difference between *Big Freeze* and *Heat Death* is.

Answer (score 3):

You must not really have looked hard enough. They are the same phenomenon

> [The Big Freeze, which is also known as the Heat Death](http://www.universetoday.com/36917/big-freeze/), is one of the possible scenarios predicted by scientists in which the Universe may end. It is a direct consequence of an ever expanding universe. The most telling evidences, such as those that indicate an increasing rate of expansion in regions farthest from us, support this theory. As such, it is the most widely accepted model pertaining to our universe’s ultimate fate.

There exist other scenaria for the end of the universe, like the [big crunch.](http://www.physicsoftheuniverse.com/topics_bigbang_bigcrunch.html)

Comment: Are they really the same, or is it just that both occur in the most likely scenario? Heat death implies a homogeneous distribution of thermal energy, regardless of the temperature. Big Freeze is either "too cold to sustain life" or temperature asymptotically approaching absolute zero due to eternal expansion.

Comment: @Previous any links?

Comment: Big freeze too cold to sustain life: http://map.gsfc.nasa.gov/universe/uni_fate.html

Comment: oops.. "Enter" button automatically submitting, and only 5 minutes to edit.
asymptotically approaches absolute zero temperature https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultimate_fate_of_the_universe
Heat death https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_death_of_the_universe (not sure if it is still mentioned on that page, or an older version was)

Comment: @Previous from your link , second paragraph, "the universe will continue expanding forever and a heat death is expected to occur,[1] with the universe cooling to approach equilibrium at a very low temperature after a very long time period."

Answer (score 0):

Heat Death and the Big Freeze are the same thing.

Comment: Welcome to physics stack exchange, please read how to answer a question at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer. Small answer without description or any explanation are not allowed. You can mention such things in the comments not as an answer.

Comment: @MurtuzaVadharia actually, that's not quite true. Anything that answers the question should be posted as an answer, not as a comment. It's not a matter of length. Of course, very short answers that don't explain things tend to be poorly received - but they are still answers.

Comment: @DavidZ Or to put it another way, it's an answer; it just happens to be an incorrect answer.

Comment: @WarrenDew or to put it another other way, it's a correct answer; it just happens to be short.

Answer (score 0):

Then we have alternatives, such as the Big Freeze transitioning into the new Big Bang in the [Conformal Cyclic Cosmology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conformal_cyclic_cosmology) Anyway, the short answer is nobody knows. There is too little known about the nature of Dark Energy especially to be able to say what the universe will be like in the far future.

Comment: Is this an accidental fragment of a longer answer? Seems to begin... strangely.

Comment: No, it's a description of Conformal Cyclic Cosmology - read the link

Comment: I'm familiar with it. Just seemed odd to start with "Then we have alternatives...". Usually "then" follows something that came before, that's all.